# Calculate time-lag between 2 variables with R

Tags: r, time-series, lag

I have 2 time series data. I need to find the time lag between this 2 variables. the dates in these 2 data sets do not coincide with each other but they are over the same period of time. I wonder if this is possible. Anyone knows how? :)

Comment: Cross-correlation might be the method of choice, but where is your sample data?

Answer (score 1):

As Dieter Menne says, cross-correlation might help.  For example

```
x <- c(1,2,1,9,1,3,2,1,3,2)
y <- c(7,9,8,7,9,8,1,7,9,8)
ccf(x, y)
```

produces

[image]

showing that the main effect happens 3 values earlier in `x` than in `y` and the relationship is negative.  Real-life examples will typically not show such a single peak.